How to include escape character as part of column value in a csv file while using apache drill?
I have a csv file like this-
"id"^"first_name"^"last_name"^"email"^"gender"
"1"^"John"^"143 \\"^"ewilkes0@buzzfeed.com"^"Male"
"2"^"Willaim"^"Khan"^"bmacdonald1@microsoft.com"^"Male"

If i execute any drill query on this then i get the following error-
UserRemoteException :  DATA_READ ERROR: Unexpected character '101' following quoted value of CSV field. Expecting '94'. Cannot parse CSV input."
But with a csv like this-
^id^|^first_name^|^last_name^|^email^|^gender^
^1^|^John^|^Bharadwaj \\^|^ewilkes0@buzzfeed.com^|^Male^
^2^|^Willaim^|^Khan^|^bmacdonald1@microsoft.com^|^Male^

Everything works fine.
This is my dfs configuration for csv in apache drill.I am using the version 1.21.1-
"csv": { "type": "text", "extensions": [ "csv" ], "lineDelimiter": "\n", "fieldDelimiter": "^", "quote": """, "escape": "\", "comment": "#", "extractHeader": true }
It seems there is some issue when escape is present just immediately before quote.
I tried changing the escape value to ~ and observed the same issue.
Any insights?

It looks the Drill CSV parser will only escape quote characters using the configured escape character and, in particular, the escape character cannot escape an occurrence of itself. I'm not sure why this limitation exists.

Looks like you are correct.
Instead of "143 \" ,even if i have data like "143 \ 5" still drill does not escape the occurrence of the escape character.In this case i dont get any error but the output is "143 \ 5" instead of "143 \5"
But the thing is i am not able to find any official documentation regarding is limitation or any workaround.

The project is very much in need of contributors. A dcumentation PR can be sent here[1], a new escaping logic PR can be sent here[2] or an ticket can opened here[3].

https://github.com/apache/drill-site
https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/a9e84a114ec8eb193ebfa8173de693e567b1c27a/exec/java-exec/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/store/easy/text/reader/TextReader.java#L249
https://issues.apache.org/jira/

